# Timing message in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple idea I just want to know what is the best way to achieve it?

I want to make a part of my website to welcome the user after user is logged in and base on time shows welcome note to user.

eg.

Good Morning, xxx.

Good Afternoon, xxxx.

like that.

PS: `xxxx` will be users username.

Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run code depending on the time of day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652502/run-code-depending-on-the-time-of-day)

Comment: @linktoahref Ok it works but how i get `{{ Auth::user()->name }}` involved?

Comment: In there in my example part i said Good Morning xxxx these `xxxx` are supposed to be usernames.

Comment: In your blade it would be something like `{{ $greetings }} {{ Auth::user()->name }}` provided `$greetings` is some variable that is been set in the controller and passed to the view

Comment: @linktoahref i get `Undefined variable: greetings` error. I've made a function named `greetings` in my `HomeController`

Comment: Please post the method of your HomeController that displays your dashboard

Comment: this shows my dashboard `public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should solve the issue

```
public function index() {

    $greetings = "";

    /* This sets the $time variable to the current hour in the 24 hour clock format */
    $time = date("H");

    /* Set the $timezone variable to become the current timezone */
    $timezone = date("e");

    /* If the time is less than 1200 hours, show good morning */
    if ($time < "12") {
        $greetings = "Good morning";
    } else

    /* If the time is grater than or equal to 1200 hours, but less than 1700 hours, so good afternoon */
    if ($time >= "12" && $time < "17") {
        $greetings = "Good afternoon";
    } else

    /* Should the time be between or equal to 1700 and 1900 hours, show good evening */
    if ($time >= "17" && $time < "19") {
        $greetings = "Good evening";
    } else

    /* Finally, show good night if the time is greater than or equal to 1900 hours */
    if ($time >= "19") {
        $greetings = "Good night";
    }

    return view('home', compact('greetings')); 
}
```

and in your blade you could do

```
{{ $greetings }} {{ Auth::user()->name }}
```

Comment: Perfect it works well, but i'm not sure why it shows greeting out of box!  http://imgur.com/a/TjFQT

Comment: You need to inspect the position where you want to display the content and render it accordingly

Comment: I've placed {{ $greetings }} same place as you see the name is printed but it shows under `<body>` tag at the top!  name is in the correct place but greetings went up!

Comment: Maybe some other blade is responsible for the content

Comment: there is only html content in that page i'm still not worked on this page is first time, i try to use /home. anyway i try to figure it out. Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper function to wrap http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison
like:

```
<?php

function say_hello(\Carbon\Carbon $carbon) {
   if($carbon->hour > 12) {
       return lang('good_morning');
   } elseif ($carbon->hour > 19) {
       return lang('good_evening');
   }
   return lang('good_afternoon');
}
```

Comment: doesn't print anything!

Comment: do uoy has lang lines for this?

Comment: no at the moment.

Answer (score -2):

In view

```
@if(session('status'))
     <div class="alert alert-success">
     {{ session('status') }}
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
     </div>
@endif
```

In Controller

```
return View::make('home')->with('status','msg');
```

Comment: yes but what about timing? how do i get what time of the day is and which message should be shown in that time of the day?

Comment: Its simple js really - 
var currentdate = new Date();
toastr.success('Great Day',currentdate);

Comment: I'm not that good with JS and also I don't have plan to use toasters/models I just want print the text top of my users dashboard and it stands there. Anyway do you have any coding sample that could help me?

Comment: No bro, you miss understood, my issue is not how to show it in view my issue is the code! i don't know what function should i write to get that result!

Comment: my bad you can use a function like @michail1982 described above.

Comment: Thanks for helping man.